# iterm2 keyboard shortcut for navigating between windows

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, iterm2

What is the keyboard shortcut for navigating between different iterm2-windows?

P.S. not but a window `Cmd+N`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is defined shortcut for navigation between windows which is `Opt + Cmd + Number` where `Number` is a number of window. (e.g. the first created window gets `1`, second `2` and etc.)

You can see/change it in:

**Preferences > Keys > Navigation Shortcuts > Shortcut to activate a window**

I hope it helps someone

Comment: By default, Mac has Cmd+~ for circling through all created windows of an application. That can also be used. But can't select specific one like using Numbers. Just an info.

Answer (score 1):

cmd+","(preferences) -> Shortcuts -> add new action with "+" and select Action: "Next Tab" Title "Next Tab" and you can switch all iterm2 windows with cmd+">" for forward switch and with cmd+shift+"<" for backward switch

Answer (score -1):

⌘⇧O to search sessions, profiles or arrangements